# Why bash redirection to a file happens in append mode

Tags: shell-script, io-redirection, file-descriptors

given this snippet:

```
exec 3>f
echo foo >&3
echo bar >&3
cat f # returns foo bar
```

Why is bash appending to f? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 21):

The thing that you are missing is that you're only opening (and truncating) the file `f` once, in the `exec` call.  The two `echo` commands are just writing to an already opened file descriptor. The file `f` will therefore not be truncated by either `echo` call.

To redirect standard output to a file descriptor, the syntax is `>&n` where `n` is some small positive integer denoting the file descriptor (there is no `>>&n` redirection).  The file descriptor has to already be associated with an opened file for this to work.  It is *the act of opening the file* and associating it with a descriptor with `exec 3>f` that truncates the file (`exec 3>>f` would not have truncated the file and would have opened it in append-mode).  Just writing with `>&3` does not open the file nor does it truncate it.

It would have been different had you done

```sh
echo foo >f
echo bar >f
cat f
```

(each `echo` is opening and truncating `f`), or, more convoluted,

```sh
exec 3>f; echo foo >&3
exec 3>f; echo bar >&3
exec 3>&- # close fd 3
cat f
```

(the file is opened and truncated by `exec` before each `echo`).